# Mapping result of aggregate query to hibernate object

Tags: hibernate, aggregate-functions

Is it possible to map the result of an aggregate query to a field in a hibernate-backed domain object?

For example: If I have a Car object that looks like the following --

```
@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id 
    private int id;
    @Column 
    private String carName;
    private int carCount;
    ---Getters/Setters---
}
```

I would like the carCount field/property to be the total count of all the cars in my persistence store, is this possible?

I've looked at the Hibernate documentation, I can run the query, but I don't see where I can set that value to the "carCount"

Thanks.

Comment: Just a comment: carCount is *not* a property for an specific instance. It's a property related to the Car class. So, it's better suited to be a "static" property. If you are using the ActiveRecord pattern, it's pretty straightforward, but if you are using some DAO pattern with "dumb" DTOs, then you'll keep this carCount outside of your DTO and implement a method in your DAO, like "int getCarCount()".

Comment: Yes, I'm using the DAO pattern. I was hoping to get away from making two calls to my DAO, but I guess I'll have to do it. Unless, of course, I want to use the @Formula annotation provided by Hibernate; but then I'm really tied to Hibernate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make it with formula. Something like,

```
@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id 
    private int id;
    @Column 
    private String carName;

    @Formula("select count(*) from Car c where c.id = id")
    private int carCount;
}
```

Also, there are some examples [here](http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/hibernate_derived_properties_performance_and).