# Hibernate JOIN SELECT

Tags: hibernate, select, join, hql, dropwizard

How can I join a table and a select statement?

In SQL it looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT p.ID,p.NAME,p.ROOM_ID,r.ATTRIBUTE FRON PERSON p INNER JOIN ROOM r ON p.ROOM_ID=r.ID) staff
INNER JOIN (
SELECT max(l.TIME) as TIME, l.PERSON_ID FROM LOG l GROUP BY l.PERSON_ID) log ON log.PERSON_ID=staff.ID
```

Comment: Do you want to convert it to HQL? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you trying to define the max(l.TIME) as a read only attribute of your hibernate mapped Person class?

Comment: Here is a post that you may find helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634820/mapping-result-of-aggregate-query-to-hibernate-object